# Can't mock android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.pattern()

Tags: android, junit4, mockk

Currently I'm using MockK library (version 1.8.1) for unit tests in Android Dev, and I the problem is I can't mock Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS. 
Test cases throw NPE every time this property gets invoked.

I tried `mockkStatic(Patterns::class)`, but @Before method crashes with NPE while applying the rule `every { Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.pattern() } returns EMAIL_REGEX_STRING`.

Class I'm trying to test:

```
public class EmailValidator {

private static final String EMPTY = "";
private final Context context;

@Inject
public EmailValidator(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public String isValidEmail(String email) {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        return context.getString(R.string.sign_up_error_email_empty);
    }

    if (!email.matches(Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.pattern())) {
        return context.getString(R.string.sign_up_error_email_validate);
    }
    return EMPTY;
}}
```

Comment: Please try 1.8.4 version, as 1.8.1 were having few issues. Also consider asking morr general questions here and use github issues for such bugreports. Thanks

Comment: @oleksiyp Thank you for the answer, I changed the version but the problem still remains...

Comment: Do you found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try using

`PatternsCompat.EMAIL_ADDRESS.pattern()`

instead of just

`Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.pattern()`

that did the job for me.

Comment: Use `androidx.core.util.PatternsCompat` instead with `android.util.Patterns`, And then use `mockk` with `mockkObject(PatternsCompat.EMAIL_ADDRESS)`, `every { PatternsCompat.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(any()).matches() } returns true`

Comment: Patterns always throws npe in a unit test for me (without mocking), although works in a normal app. PatternsCompat works in the unit test also for me.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS` directly, you could create a wrapper around it then mock or fake the wrapper.

The wrapper could be a method, like:

```
class EmailValidator {
    fun isValidEmail(email: String) {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            return context.getString(R.string.sign_up_error_email_empty);
        }

        if (!email.matches(getEmailPattern())) {
            return context.getString(R.string.sign_up_error_email_validate);
        }
    }

    private fun getEmailPattern(): String = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.pattern()
}
```

and your test could mock it like:

```
@Test
fun `test email validator`() {
    val validator = spyk(EmailValidator())

    every { validator["getEmailPattern"]() } returns yourTestPattern

    assertThat(validator.isValidEmail("blah blah blah")).isFalse()
}
```

Or create a class that wraps it, maybe a PatternFactory class

```
class PatternFactory {
    fun getEmailPattern(): String = ...
    fun getVinPattern(): String = ...
}
```

then pass in `PatternFactory` in as a dependency and mock it for the test